# Python execute program change path

Tags: python, path, executable

I'm trying to make a Python script run another program from its own path.

I've got the execution of the other program working using os.system, but the program will crash because it cannot find its resources (wrong path, I assume). I tried adding the folder harboring the executable to the path, but that didn't help.

Comment: Can you post some sample code for the attempt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the current directory of your script with `os.chdir`().  You can also set environment variables with `os.environ`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html), and use the `cwd` argument to set the child's working directory.

Answer (score 1):

These two methods from the os library will do the work:os.chdir and os.system.

```
path = "C://Program Files//Microsoft SQL Server//Client 
SDK//ODBC//130//Tools//Binn//" #make sure to use forward slash
program = "bcp.exe"
os.chdir(path)
os.system(program)
```